# SQL server case statement

Tags: sql-server

I have the following case statement that I am struggling to get to work.  I can see what the problem is but am unsure on how to fix it.

```
CASE 
WHEN DateDiff(n,Oppo_Opened,GetDate()) <  CASE WHEN CONVERT(Time, Oppo_Opened) > '16:00:00' THEN 960 ELSE 60 END THEN 60 - DateDiff(n,Oppo_Opened,GetDate())
WHEN DateDiff(n,Oppo_Opened,GetDate())  < CASE WHEN CONVERT(Time, Oppo_Opened) > '14:00:00' THEN 1080 ELSE 180 END  THEN 180 - DateDiff(n,Oppo_Opened,GetDate())
WHEN CONVERT(Date,DATEADD(hh,7.5,getdate())) =  CONVERT(Date,Oppo_Opened) THEN DateDiff(n,CONVERT(Time, GetDate()),'17:30:00')
WHEN GetDate()<  Oppo_Opened + 1 THEN DateDiff(n,GetDate(),Oppo_Opened +1)
ELSE 0 
END Mins
```

The first 2 when statements are always using either the 60 or 180 and subtracts from the Datediff statement, but it should use either the 960/60 depending on the previous statement.  I am hoping this makes sense to someone.

Comment: I'm not sure I am following your issue. At the end of the the first WHEN line, you subtract DateDiff(n,Oppo_Opened,GetDate()) from 60. If you are saying that the "60" in this case should be either 960 or 60 based on the prior CASE statement, then replace the last "60" on that line with a separate embedded CASE statement that returns either 960 or 60. Repeat the same approach for the 180 in the second line. Is this the direction you are looking to go in?

Comment: Thanks for your response, how do I structure this ?

Comment: Let me ask a question I should have asked before.... Can you explain in English what you are trying to achieve? At the very least, what the first rule should be. e.g. "If the time of Oppo_Opened is after 4pm,the result should be 960, otherwise it should be 60. From this value, I need to subtract the number of minutes between now and Opp_Opened." ... or whatever.

Comment: Our working day is 8am till 5pm.  There are three stages to a enquiry, 1 hour , 3 hours and same day quote.  Id the enquiry is opened after 4pm, then they can fit in a hour quote.  If this is not managed the next stage is 3 hours, this gives them up until 10am the following morning to do this.

Comment: And the output, "Mins", what does that represent?

Comment: The number of minutes left before the next stage is reached

Comment: I think this question may not be the best fit for SuperUser.com. I suggest you ask the question in StackOverflow, being as specific as possible, and also including a series of input values and the expected output values (especially if they can demonstrate the different stages you described).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Shoeless maybe you can break case statements. You can do this defining an scalar function or declaring an int variable

```
declare @before16 as int
declare @before14 as int

set @before16 = CASE WHEN CONVERT(Time, Oppo_Opened) > '16:00:00' 
                     THEN 960
                     ELSE 60 
                END
set @before14 = CASE WHEN CONVERT(Time, Oppo_Opened) > '14:00:00'
                     THEN 1080 
                     ELSE 180
                END
```

then you can make substitution:

```
CASE WHEN DateDiff(n,Oppo_Opened,GetDate()) <  @before16
          THEN @before16 - DateDiff(n,Oppo_Opened,GetDate())
     WHEN DateDiff(n,Oppo_Opened,GetDate())  < @before14
          THEN @before14 - DateDiff(n,Oppo_Opened,GetDate())
     WHEN CONVERT(Date,DATEADD(hh,7.5,getdate())) = CONVERT(Date,Oppo_Opened) 
          THEN DateDiff(n,CONVERT(Time, GetDate()),'17:30:00')
     WHEN GetDate() < Oppo_Opened + 1 
          THEN DateDiff(n,GetDate(),Oppo_Opened +1)
     ELSE 0 
END Mins
```